# Por que devo usar apenas um "return" em cada função?

Tags: funções, estilo-de-codificação, return

É comum vermos a recomendação de usar apenas um `return` por função/método. Mas isso parece algo sem sentido e deixa o código mais confuso em muitos casos.

#### Veja os exemplos:

Forma como eu costumo fazer:

```c
if (cond)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
```

Forma como é recomendado:

```c
int resultado;
if (cond)
    resultado = 0;
else
    resultado = 1;
return resultado;
```

Por que há essa recomendação? O que se ganha em usar um único `return`?

Comment: Considero as vezes melhor haver apenas um return porque você pode depurar o resultado do método facilmente. Verificando o que sai em `resultado` neste caso (pois se não for assim, você precisará de colocar duas inspeções ou mais, uma para cada return, para ver aonde o método está entrando). Em compensação isso as vezes aumenta a complexidade ciclomática também.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

## Não deve, faça o que for melhor para a legibilidade do código

Basicamente essa regra é chamada de [Single Entry, Single Exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-entry_single-exit) (SESE) e é uma recomendação importante em **linguagens que usam gerenciamento explícito (ou manual) de memória**. Especialmente em linguagens que não contam com tratamento de erros por exceções.

É importante perceber que o uso de **SESE quase sempre torna o código mais complexo**.

Em linguagens como C, por exemplo, quando você precisa explicitamente liberar recursos alocados no final da execução da função, há a necessidade de replicar a liberação desses recursos antes de cada `return` e corre-se o risco de haver confusão quando existem vários deles. Se houver qualquer confusão, o código da função acaba terminando a execução da mesma sem fazer a liberação ou fazendo de forma indevida.

## Gerenciamento de recursos e exceções

**Em linguagens que fazem uso de exceções, SESE já faz ainda menos sentido** já que qualquer função chamada potencialmente pode gerar uma saída da função atualmente em execução. Mesmo que você possa se valer da documentação para saber se uma função usada pode emitir uma exceção, terminando a função atual, você tem em mãos uma dificuldade de entendimento do código de manutenção futura.

Em C++, por exemplo, onde exceções existem, é fundamental o uso de gerenciamento automático ou semi-automático de recursos através da técnica chamada [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). Em Java e C# existem construções como `try-finally` e `using` para lidar com liberação de recursos.

Já que o programa pode ter vários pontos de saída implícitos, através do lançamento de exceções, onde você nem sabe de onde vem, não adianta tentar unificar a saída explícita em um único ponto. Você vai criar um fluxo confuso no código e não vai resolver qualquer problema.

Em linguagens com tratamento de exceção você tem duas situações:

- a existência de recursos que facilitam a chamada "saída limpa" liberando todos os recursos aconteça o que acontecer;
- a ineficácia da técnica já que sempre pode existir vários pontos de saída invisíveis em qualquer função chamada que emita um `throw` ou `raise`.

Então a técnica SESE se tornou desnecessária e até não recomendada já que em muitos casos o fluxo do programa acaba sendo complicado em nome da confiabilidade da saída única.

Infelizmente ainda há quem ache isso importante em qualquer linguagem e dissemina uma informação que é parcialmente obsoleta, como ocorre em muitos outros casos de "boas práticas" propagandeadas.

A **legibilidade do código e a facilidade de manutenção são mais importantes** que um guia que não traz nenhum benefício em linguagens que possuem ferramentas próprias para gerenciamento e liberação de recursos. É comum  termos a [complexidade ciclomática](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) reduzida quando utilizamos vários `return` fazendo que a execução da função termine o quanto antes.

É evidente que fazer uso correto do `return` e manter uma lógica coerente ainda é necessário não importando quantas vezes ele aparece no corpo da função.

## Uso legítimo

Mas vejamos um caso em que o uso do SESE seria legítimo e solucionaria um problema existente, como é comum acontecer na linguagem C:

```c
void funcao1() {
  resource recurso = acquire_resource();  //talvez possa ser um malloc() aqui
  if( funcao2(recurso) )
    return; // esqueceu do código de liberação antes do return e o recurso vazou
  .
  .
  .
  funcao3(recurso);
  release_resource(recurso);  //poderia ser um free()
  return;
}
```

Com SESE:

```c
void funcao1() {
  resource recurso = acquire_resource();  //talvez possa ser um malloc() aqui
  if( funcao2(recurso) )
    goto saida; // manda para o ponto onde o recurso é liberado e termina a função
  .
  .
  .
  funcao3(recurso);
saida:
  release_resource(recurso);  //poderia ser um free()
  return;
}
```

Em linguagens assim você tem algumas opções:

- Repetir o código de liberação do recurso

  Solução horrorosa e facilita a criação de erros, fere o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101)
- Colocar um `goto` para o trecho do código que faz a liberação de recursos

  O código de liberação deve ser a última parte da função e é um dos melhores usos para o `goto`
- Criar uma variável local para ajudar o controle de fluxo do programa

  É bem mais complicado controlar o fluxo desta forma do que usando controles da linguagem que guardam o estado para o controle do fluxo implicitamente.

Como essas linguagens trazem essas dificuldades, foi criada a técnica do SESE que manda existir apenas um ponto de saída, ou seja um único `return`.

Fica bem mais fácil padronizar esta técnica. Se o programador tem na cabeça que sempre deve fazer isto, como se fosse obrigado pela linguagem, a chance dele esquecer de fazer a liberação é bem menor.

## Conclusão

Precisamos usar técnicas apropriadas para cada linguagem. Tentar usar uma técnica criada para uma linguagem em outras acabam criando as interpretações erradas do tipo "*`goto` nunca deve ser usado*" e "*comentários devem estar espalhados por todo programa detalhando tudo o que o programa faz*", etc.

Certamente este *post* não encerra o assunto e seria interessante ver informações adicionais. Deixei alguns pontos de fora para dar oportunidade de outras pessoas complementarem.

[Coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/Sese.c).

---

Esta resposta é baseada na encontrada em [Where did the notion of “one return only” come from?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118717/389)

Comment: Eu nunca engoli essa história que "goto é sempre ruim", mas nunca tinha visto um caso prático em que ele fosse claramente útil e sem boas alternativas. +1

Comment: Realmente nunca havia visto um exemplo prático mostrando um benefício da utilização do goto. +1

Comment: Outro exemplo prático são os usados pelo csc onde loops e instruções de fluxo são substituídos por goto's.

Comment: Esse exemplo de `goto` não me convenceu. É só fazer `if ( !funcao2(recurso) ) { funcao3(recurso); } release_resource(recurso); return;` que o `goto` pode ser dispensado, ficando até mais evidente qual é a lógica por trás do fluxo da função. Se não houver um exemplo melhor, só vejo o `goto` sendo indispensável em assembly e bytecode. Não à toa, BASIC é considerada uma linguagem ruim para iniciantes em programação e Java priva o uso da palavra-chave `goto`.

Comment: Quando eu fizer a pergunta sobre o `goto` você verá que não é bem assim. Não quis dar um exemplo completo porque esta questão não é sobre `goto`.

Comment: @bigown Ok. Quando postar, por favor informe o link.

Comment: _"SESE quase sempre torna o código mais complexo"_, _"Temos a complexidade ciclomática reduzida quando fazemos o fluxo terminar o quanto antes"_ - no tópico em inglês o único argumento para essas afirmações é quando se adiciona uma variável local e **a usa para fazer controle de fluxo**. Não acho que seja o caso em todas as situações.

Comment: _"Em linguagens que fazem uso de exceções, SESE faz menos sentido"_ - em uma manutenção você pode querer acrescentar código imediatamente antes do (preferencialmente único) ponto de retorno, por exemplo uma chamada a função de log ou outra função qualquer.

Comment: Tem desenvolvedor que evita lógica negativa (`if (!condição)`) por achar difícil de ler. Isso sugere uma deficiência/comodismo em lógica de programação e leva a uma tendência a espalhar `return`'s pela função quando a condição negativa é invertida para uma positiva. Evitar lógica negativa não deveria ser desculpa para não aplicar SE.

Comment: @bigown realmente esse preconceito de que isso ou aquilo não deve ser usado cai sempre no mesmo: desconhecimento. É como discutir se com ou sem OOP é melhor, se if sem { } pode ou não, etc. O bom programador usa o que é melhor na hora que é melhor, o programador mediano só usa o pouco que domina, e o mau programador repete o que ouve da maioria, pois não tem como discernir.

Comment: O problema de usar `goto` é que ele dificulta a manutenção do código pois ele fragmenta os "fluxos de execução de código". Um código com vários gotos pode ter fluxo do código que começa em cima, vai para baixo, volta pro meio... Isso geralmente é indesejável. Como no exemplo já dado pelo @Piovezan, nesse exemplo é possível refatorar o código para ter uma condição `if/else` muito mais legível e fácil de dar manutenção.

Comment: Os casos em que os benefícios do uso de `goto` supera seus malefícios são muito restritos. Tão restritos que se você disser que "`goto` é sempre ruim", você provavelmente vai estar errado _menos de 1% das vezes_. :)

Comment: Eu exemplifiquei o uso de `goto` em casos como este [nesta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3339958/176769), anos atrás.

Comment: qual o problema em: ler um `goto LABEL` e procurar tal `LABEL`, seguindo a leitura a partir dela? Existem tantas pessoas que são tão limitadas na nossa área? Um programador que se preze precisa entender o que o `goto` faz e entender como ler um programa usando ele. Coisa ridícula isso de que `goto é sempre ruim`.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Ninguém falou que é sempre ruim, só 99% das vezes. :) O problema é que esse `LABEL` pode estar em *literalmente qualquer lugar*, acima ou abaixo do `goto`, talvez em um ponto totalmente desconexo do fluxo que você estava acompanhando quando chegou no `goto`, por exemplo em uma outra função. Código-espaguete é quase sinônimo de código com muitos `goto's`. O problema não é o programador saber ler um `goto` esporádico, e sim querer perpetuá-lo em novos códigos de maneira desenfreada. Em 99% dos casos existem estruturas de controle melhores e mais previsíveis para se usar.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade 1 `goto` é uma barbadinha de entender. O problema é quando a gente pega um código espaguete que fica jogando o fluxo pra lá e pra cá o tempo inteiro. Fica quase impossível saber quais variáveis foram inicializadas e qual o valor delas.

Comment: Sempre discordei deste único return, pelo menos agora tenho um bom argumento. Ainda mais hoje em dia em que existem muitos IDEs onde se depura código e pode-se ver o ciclo

Answer (score 71):

*Atenção: A resposta do @Maniero (para a pergunta do @Maniero :) está claramente correta. Minha resposta é mais curta e direta, mas meramente complementar, com o objetivo de salientar um ponto que considero importante.*

Para linguagens em um nível mais alto (com gerenciamento automático de memória: C#, Java, JavaScript, Python etc.) na verdade chega até a haver um consenso em **não utilizar o formato descrito na pergunta como "recomendado"**.

Só dar uma olhada, por exemplo, nas respostas a [esta pergunta do programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) (em Inglês).

Manter um único `return` *tende* a tornar o método mais complexo, com vários níveis de `if`s e `else`s. Já o *"early returning"*, pelo contrário, permite ao programador "se livrar" de condições mais fáceis de identificar, que exigem menos processamento (normalmente associadas a pré-condições de erro, ou que não permitam a execução completa da rotina). Logo, facilitando a escrita.

Isso também deixa o código mais simples de compreender, pois o método acaba se dividindo naturalmente em duas partes: um início composto de pré-condições de saída rápida, e o código que efetua o processamento propriamente dito, quando as condições de entrada forem satisfeitas. Logo, facilitando a manutenção.

Uma forma ainda melhor seria justamente utilizar pré-condições explícitas, ou [*programação-por-contrato*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_contrato), em linguagens que tenham suporte a isso (tais como Eiffel, por exemplo).

Comment: Excelente complemento! Ao estilo Eric Lippert :)

Comment: Perfeito. Muita gente (eu me incluo) sempre tomou como base a prática SESE para qualquer que fosse a linguagem de programação usada.

Answer (score 22):

Discutindo questão paralela...

### MEDOS

Como a pergunta refere-se a qualquer linguagem, qualquer situação... Me recordei de situações onde o problema não era estilo, elegância, legibilidade, etc. mas o comportamento lógico da função. O uso mal pensado do *return*, ou a visão de um monte de *returns*, dá um certo "medo de errar", de surgirem bugs misteriosos...

Me recordo de três situações típicas:

1. Quando o algoritmo é complexo, cheio de ramificações, e desejo "provar" que ele termina ([problema clássico da Computação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))... Aí creio que devemos nos lembrar também da regra do ***"para todo IF um ELSE"***, que ajuda a verificar algebricamente se tem return para todas as situações.
2. Quando existe **recorrência**: como vai ficar a pilha de recorrência?
3. Quando a linguagem não estabelece com clareza a "encerramento de tudo" após o return.

Comment: Excelente complemento.

Answer (score 13):

resposta rápida seria em relação a Manutenibilidade do código, o fato de existir apenas um return ajuda a mapear com facilidade o fluxo dentro do método ou função

Comment: Aumentar a complexidade ciclomática facilita mapear o fluxo?