# Omitir o else é uma boa ideia em alguns casos, ou não?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, else

Me faço essa pergunta toda vez que estou codificando, pois sempre tenho a preocupação de deixar meu código compreensível aos demais programadores que irão contemplá-lo - e a mim mesmo, pois talvez eu não vou lembrar o que fiz ali.

Seria uma boa ideia omitirmos o `else` em algumas ocasiões, como nesse caso?

```
$usuario = Usuario::find($id);

if (is_null($usuario)) {
    return Response::json(['error' => 'Usuário não encontrado');
}


return Response::json(['error' => false, 'usuario' => $usuario]);
```

Ou, por alguma questão de legibilidade, eu deveria fazer assim?

```
$usuario = Usuario::find($id);

if (is_null($usuario)) {

    return Response::json(['error' => 'Usuário não encontrado');

} else {

    return Response::json(['error' => false, 'usuario' => $usuario]);

}
```

Em que poderia ser prejudicial a colocação (ou não) do `else` (em casos como esses, para facilitar)?

Comment: Acho isso bem pessoal. Eu prefiro omitir o `else` nesses casos. Vai ter gente falando que nenhum presta porque você não deveria ter mais de um `return` na função.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu prefiro fazer isso do que criar uma variável chamada `$return` e ir atribuindo os dados da resposta nela. Isso pode deixar mais confuso do que o a omissão do `else` em si. A questão é simplificar. Se ter dois `return` simplifica, então, por que não?

Comment: Eu meio que concordo com você. Não sou desses fundamentalistas de um return só :) Mas acho que pergunta está bem baseada em opinião, olha a resposta que já apareceu.

Comment: Então nesse caso, eu concordo em fechar minha própria pergunta @bfavaretto

Comment: Vamos esperar mais um pouco pra ver o que os outros acham.

Comment: @bfavaretto Quando eu era criança eu achava que devia ter um só return, até perceber que o problema não eram os múltiplos returns mas sim os blocos de código gigantescos com muitas responsabilidades - nestes um return perdido no meio ferrava com tudo mesmo :D

Comment: Tá aí uma outra pergunta: _Usar múltipos returns é uma má prática_?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Taí uma resposta: não, não é ;-) Método com mais de uma responsabilidade é que é uma má prática. Se o método tem só uma responsabilidade ele é naturalmente curto e os múltiplos returns não vão prejudicar sua expressividade nem causar confusão.

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que devo usar apenas um “return” em cada função?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/91)

Comment: Apesar de a pergunta instigar as opniões, têm muitas opniões que são boas para você aprender a fazer algo útil na programação

Comment: Eu sempre deixo um `return` apenas. E omito o `else` quando não é necessário. Acho estéticamente feio.

Comment: Também omito o else e não acho problemático mais de um return. Sou da opinião do @Caffé: mais importante do que isso, é separar bem as responsabilidades.

Answer (score 1):

Não queria ser chato, mas dá pra melhorar mais ainda:

```
$usuario = Usuario::find($id);
//se for nulo, retorna 'false', caso contrário, retorna a mensagem
$msg = (is_null($usuario)) ? false : 'Usuário não encontrado';
return Response::json(['error' => $msg, 'usuario' => $usuario]);
```

Reduzir o código melhora a compreensão e a leitura. Simplesmente assim.

Comment: Discordo. Reduzir o código nem sempre melhora a comprensão e a leitura. Fica meio engessado

Comment: Melhor é seguir a normalização, a partir do PSR-4, do http://www.php-fig.org/

Comment: Mas o padrão de codificação do PHP não é o PSR-2?

Comment: Não faça duas vezes o que pode ser feito uma única vez.

Comment: Bom, pra mim um `if` ternário é mais ilegível do que um `if else` normal.

Comment: Bom, quanto mais linhas você usar no código, mais linhas vc terá que ler. Então... para entender a diferença entre um ternário é um `if else`, basta saber que ambas existem. Obviamente que vc usar o ternário mais de uma vez na mesma linha, irá dificultar a compreensão.

Comment: O que quero dizer é que você sempre pode melhorar seu código para que a máquina tome uma decisão mais rápida por você, isso facilita a compreensão sistêmica. Um programador deve ter a mesma habilidade de compreensão sistêmica, isso não significa necessariamente escrever um código menos legível ao desenvolvedor, mas unir os dois mundos é o ideal. Mas existe @annotations e //comentários para auxiliar a compreensão e infelizmente poucas pessoas fazem uso dela, ou pelo menos bom uso delas.

Comment: Não concordo que este código seja mais legível. Mesmo considerando que a sintaxe do PHP faz todas as outras alternativas parecerem excessivamente complexas, condicionais ternárias são desnecessariamente obscuras.

Comment: "Se todas as regras não funcionaram, então fugimos delas". Essa é a lógica que eu considero "bagunça", agora como você acha melhor escrever isso para mim tanto faz, esteticamente, eu prefiro usar `ternário` porque eu sou chato mesmo, "não queria mais sou",  e gosto de ver tudo na mesma linha. Se vai ter muitas regras ou condicionais, eu prefiro separá-los em novos métodos. Sou plenamente a favor do polimorfismo.

Answer (score 1):

Depende muito da necessidade da lógica, dependendo poderia usar uma outra forma:

```
if(condicao)
{
   //alguma logica
}
else
{
   //alguma logica
}

return resultado;
```

Mas em usar `else` e omitir o `else`, dá na mesma, pois, se não entrar no `if`, automaticamente vai para a lógica abaixo.

Comment: Segundo http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ Essa formatação é apropriada somente para classes e métodos.

Answer (score 0):

**Qual a função do *else*?**

> É fornecer o código que deve ser executado no caso de (e somente no caso de) a condição do *if* não ser verdadeira.

No seu exemplo, no caso de a condição do *if* ser verdadeira, o código depois dele jamais será executado pois há um *return* dentro do bloco *if*, e no caso de não ser verdadeira todo o código depois do *if* sempre será executado; logo, o *else* ali é redundante.

Se você aceitar a premissa de que código redundante é desnecessário, o *else* no seu exemplo é desnecessário.