# Deve-se usar break em for?

Tags: loop, independente-de-linguagem

Tenho uma dúvida sobre os laços de repetições. Tive uma aula em que meu professor disse que jamais se deve usar o **for** se não for executar ele do inicio até o fim.

Só que já vi muitos, muitos códigos usando essa estrutura de repetição contendo um **break** no meio para parar.

Isso é errado?  Qual o problema de querer iterar em cima de uma lista e caso encontrar o que deseja, parar ?

Eu comentei isso com ele e o mesmo afirma que nesses casos, não devo usar o **for** porque não seria uma solução/estratégia elegante.

Isso procede ? Em casos que eu tenha que parar a laço no meio, devo optar por **while** ou **do while** e só usar o **for** para casos que vou processar todos os elementos do x até N?

Comment: Será que quando ele afirmou isso, ele estava pensando no `for` que utilizamos definindo um número de tanto a tanto que queremos iterar. Porque nesse caso, se sabemos o número, não haveria necessidade de utilizar o `break`. Devemos lembrar que o `for` pode ser utilizado para muitas outras operações, além de incrementações de `1..9`.

Comment: Ele estava dando exemplos com todos os operadores e afirmando que for deve ser e somente usado para casos que sabemos de quanto até quando ir. Nos outros casos, deviamos optar por do while ou while.. Por isso fiquei confuso em relação a isso, porque eu uso muito o for pra iterar lista e procurar algo que eu quero e parar o processo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mesmo neste caso pode ter várias razões para quebrar o `for`. É comum termos código que deve ter que ir do 0 à 9 a não ser que ele descubra algo no meio do caminho. Só será ridículo se fizer um `for` desta forma e tiver uma quebra assim: `if (i == 5) break;`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que você não entendeu o que escrevi, mas tudo bem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Não sei se ele está falando de alguma linguagem específica. Vou falar em termos gerais.

Algumas pessoas são dogmáticas.

Até tem algum sentido esta opção. Semanticamente o `for` indicaria que você quer ir de um ponto a outro e não deveria haver interrupções. Algumas pessoas dirão que se é para haver uma interrupção então use um `while`. Me parece um preciosismo que não dá vantagem, certamente nenhuma técnica. No máximo passa a ideia que ele pode parar à qualquer momento e não precisa ir até o fim como fora especificado no `for`. Isto se todos os envolvidos com o código seguem esta regra.

Não tem erro algum nisto, mas se você trabalha em uma equipe (sua aula é sua equipe neste momento) e ela diz que deve seguir esta regra, siga-a. Não sem questionar, claro, como você está fazendo. Isto é bom. Mas se não tem um problema em seguir a regra estabelecida e "todos" concordam com ela, não seja diferente.

Elegância depende um pouco de gosto. Algumas coisas são universais, outras não. Pro meu gosto eu não seguiria isto cegamente. Poderia ser que algum caso eu escolhesse uma construção ou outra por outros motivos mas dificilmente por este apresentado.

Até mesmo a performance poderia me fazer escolher um ou outro, em algumas situações específicas.

Olhando a resposta do OnoSendai me veio algo à cabeça: você faz um `for` que vai do início ao fim, aí um belo dia precisa mudar a implementação e encontra uma situação que precisa ter uma interrupção em determinada situação. Você seria "obrigado" a trocar o `for` pelo `while`? Pra que? Pode fazer, mas não me parece algo necessário, algo que vai acrescentar algo à clareza do código, pelo contrário. Eu acho que em alguns casos usar um `while` quando varrerá uma sequência, mesmo que ela possa ser interrompida pode até deixar menos claro o que aquilo é de fato. Acho menos claro, mas não muito menos, também não me oporia fortemente a esta mudança, o código ainda seria claro o suficiente.

## Motivos para escolher um dos dois

Um bom motivo para optar pelo `while` é quando a variável de controle será usada fora do laço.

Talvez a principal vantagem do `for` sobre o `while` é justamente encapsular a variável de controle no escopo do laço. Se não precisa disto, o `for` perde força.

Se não inicializar a variável fora do laço sobra a condição, que o `while` tem, e o passo a ser executado em cada repetição.

Este passo já é criticado por algumas pessoas já que ele é escrito no início do laço mas só é executado no final dele. Lembrando que a condição é executada no começo.

Claro que não há problema em declarar e/ou inicializar a variável fora do laço usando um `for`. Só tem menos vantagens.

E é bom lembrar que há linguagens que não há escopo em bloco interno no código de uma função, então isto não faz diferença nelas.

Mas o grande motivo para escolher uma das duas construções é justamente quando haverá interrupção do fluxo normal mas ainda dentro do laço. Como se deseja que o passo seja executado se houver um salto para o fim do laço? Quer que ele seja executado sempre ou o passo deve ser omitido se houver um salto? Exemplo:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
    if (condiçao) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

O `i` será incrementado mesmo que entre no `if` e o fluxo seja desviado. Já:

```
i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
    ...
    if (condiçao) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
    i++;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/ForVsWhile.ptg).

Pulará o incremento do `i` quando entrar no `if`. Isto é uma mudança semântica que produz um resultado muito diferente. E não é fácil simular isto usando a construção errada. Algumas pessoas poderão tentar e causar problemas maiores, até mesmo uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

O professor falou sobre isto? Se não, espero que fale na próxima aula, porque isto é algo fundamental para se saber sobre a escolha de uma ou a outra construção. Esta tem implicações práticas reais no código.

## Evitar interrupções

A resposta do mgibsonbr fala bem sobre isto. O ideal é não ter `break` ou até mesmo um `continue`. Isto é um `goto` e todo mundo sabe que [`goto` é do demônio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) (por favor, leia minha resposta no *link* para entender o sarcasmo).

Bom, é uma forma melhor de `goto` e apesar de procurarmos evitar este tipo de construção, não se deve fazer isto a qualquer custo. Se for pra escrever um código convoluto, é preferível por `break` ou `continue`, ou até mesmo um `goto` em casos bem mais raros e deixar o código mais claro.

O mesmo vale para um `return` que é um `break` mais agressivo. E [usar um `return`, até mesmo dentro de um laço, não é algo ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/101).

Comment: +1 pelo ponto interessante - normalização de código. Se um time de desenvolvimento utiliza um ou outro como padrão, siga-o sempre; muito melhor do que 20 excelentes estilos de implementação é um estilo bom e único.

Comment: Entendi e concordo com seguir os padrões já adotados pela equipe. O real problema que isso me trouxe foi me fazer pensar que todo código que escrevi usando o for e interrompendo ele poderia ter sido escrito de uma forma muito ruim. Enfim, muito obrigado pela resposta, me deu uma ótima clareza em relação a isso. :)

Answer (score 11):

Em senso estrito, **não procede**. Em várias situações reais você possui objetos que podem mudar de estado durante a execução de um laço, e o tratamento pode induzir a uma avaliação de que o laço não é mais necessário ou válido - sendo a interrupção do laço a atitude mais desejada.

Outro fator seria performance. Em C#, por exemplo, os mecanismos de controle da linguagem podem fazer com que [um laço `for` seja mais performático do que um `while`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629174/which-loop-is-faster-while-or-for).

Comment: Exatamente. Em muitas situações sabemos o inicio e fim do nosso laço e por isso podemos optar pelo for, só que ninguém garante que nenhum estado de objeto mude e que precisamos tomar outra medida.

Answer (score 10):

Interromper um laço no meio (qualquer laço, não só o `for`) traz uma desvantagem que é tornar mais difícil para o programador entender em que estado o programa está. Independentemente da construção empregada, esse problema existe. Às vezes é inevitável, mas quando puder estruturar seu código de modo a torná-lo mais claro pros leitores humanos, vale a pena fazê-lo.

Quanto ao `for`, eu quebraria seu uso em dois casos basicamente:

1. A variável de controle do `for` é exclusiva do mesmo, não sendo usada em mais nenhum lugar.

   Exemplo:

   ```
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < lista.length ; i++ ) {
       ...
       if ( condição )
           break;
   }
   ```

   Qual será o valor de `i` ao final do loop? Ora, isso é irrelevante! Ninguém vai usar `i` fora do loop, aliás dependendo da linguagem `i` nem existirá mais nesse momento. De modo que o uso do `break` não atrapalha em nada a compreensão do código.
2. A variável de controle do `for` é usada mais de uma vez, talvez até por mais de um loop.

   Exemplo:

   ```
   // Remove um elemento de uma lista
   int indice;
   for ( indice = 0; indice < alvo ; indice++ )
       destino[indice] = origem[indice];
   for ( indice++ ; indice < origem.length ; indice++ )
       destino[indice-1] = origem[indice];
   ```

   Nesse caso, se o primeiro `for` tivesse um `break`, qual seria o valor de `indice` após seu término? Poderia ser qualquer um, e você teria de programar com muito cuidado para não presumir um valor incorreto. Observar a condição de parada do `for` não te ajuda, pois o valor de `indice` não seria necessariamente igual a `alvo` no fim do primeiro loop, nem igual a `origem.length` no fim do segundo.

   Usar um `while` nesse caso ajudaria? Pouco - você ainda não saberia qual o estado exato de `indice` após cada loop. A utilidade ou não do mesmo depende das **expectativas** do programador ao ler o código. Se você já espera que um `while` possa conter `break`s, mas não espera que o mesmo ocorra com um `for`, então você prestará mais atenção a esse detalhe se for usado um `while`. Caso contrário, não faz diferença nenhuma...

O pronto chave é ajustar as expectativas de quem está lendo seu código com o que o código faz de fato. Se todos concordarem com uma convenção, então o melhor a fazer é segui-la, ou ao menos documentar cada vez que você se desvia dessa convenção (por um bom motivo, de preferência). Afinal, não faz diferença dirigir pela esquerda ou pela direita, desde que **todos** dirijam pelo mesmo lado... ;)

Comment: Bons exemplos, principalmente o segundo caso!! Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, foi de muita ajuda!!

Comment: Um exemplo razoável de quando deve preferir o `while` é justamente quando a variável de controle deve ser usada fora do laço, independente de haver quebra ou não.

Answer (score 5):

Talvez isso dependa da linguagem. Mas isso seria mais uma questão de boa prática recomendada pelo seu professor, do que ter "um certo" e "um errado".
Digo isso porque existem pessoas que usam de afirmações como "não se pode fazer isso".

Existe casos de linguagens, como o `Python`, por exemplo, onde podemos utilizamos um `for` para outro tipos de iterações (como listas, objetos, generators), o que não é comum em outras linguagens.

Uma expressão que retornasse um generator infinito, por exemplo, poderia ser necessário a utilização de um `break` para encerrar esse laço infinito.

Em outros casos, em linguagens como `PHP`, onde podemos utilizar um `foreach` para iterar com um `array` ou um `Iterator`, não há necessidade da utilização do `for`.

Comment: Sim, também achei que é questão de boas práticas recomendada por ele.  Mas foi um ponto bem interessante, me fez pensar muito nos códigos que fiz até hoje, e como tenho pouco tempo na área, nunca achei que isso poderia ser um "problema".