# Qual diferença entre o return e o break em um switch case?

Tags: java, android, return, switch, break

Em algumas situações é necessário a prática do [`switch case`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) para otimização e melhoria de código. Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida para Android usando Java, que no caso é utilizado das duas situações. Abaixo tenho um exemplo usando `return` no qual é usado com `Tabs`:

```
switch (position){
    case 0:
        Tab tab1 = new Tab1();
        return tab1;
    case 1:
        Tab tab2 = new Tab2();
        return  tab2;
    case 2:
        Tab tab3 = new Tab3();
        return tab3;
}
```

Neste caso abaixo temos que o uso do `break` no qual é definido o mês desejado:

```
    int month = 8;
    String monthString;
    switch (month) {
        case 1:  monthString = "January";
                 break;
        case 2:  monthString = "February";
                 break;
        case 3:  monthString = "March";
                 break;
        case 4:  monthString = "April";
                 break;
        case 5:  monthString = "May";
                 break;
        case 6:  monthString = "June";
                 break;
        case 7:  monthString = "July";
                 break;
        case 8:  monthString = "August";
                 break;
        case 9:  monthString = "September";
                 break;
        case 10: monthString = "October";
                 break;
        case 11: monthString = "November";
                 break;
        case 12: monthString = "December";
                 break;
        default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                 break;
    }
```

No SO gringo, tem [uma explicação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620991/2570426)<sup>(en)</sup>, mas não entendi exatamente o que diverge um do outro. Qual real diferença entre o `return` e o `break` em um `switch case`?

Comment: O break quebra apenas o fluxo do switch, ou seja, ele interrompe a continuidade desde bloco. O return quebra o fluxo do método ao qual ele faz parte.

Comment: Lembrando que o `switch` é uma das construções de linguagem mais horrorosas que existe no Java. Ele foi herdado do C e do C++, já sendo uma coisa horrorosa desde que nasceu no C. Evite utilizá-lo, só o use se realmente não conseguir achar nada que fique melhor.

Comment: @VictorStafusa bom, mas talvez, eu digo talvez, seja melhor que usar um linguição de "ifelse". Por um acaso existe alguma outra alternativa?!

Comment: @AckLay, sim existe. No primeiro caso dá para fazer (com o Java 8) `Supplier<Tab1> a = Tab1::new; Supplier<Tab2> b = Tab2::new; Supplier<Tab3> c = Tab3::new; return Arrays.asList(a, b, c).get(position).get();`. No seu segundo caso você pode usar `String[] meses = {"Invalid month", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}; String monthString = meses[month < 1 || month > 12 ? 0 : month];`

Comment: @VictorStafusa legal. vou fazer uma busca profunda sobre esse lado. Mas essa opção de não usar `switch` é uma questão performática ou só questão de opinião?

Comment: @AckLay é uma questão de legibilidade e manutenibilidade de código. O `switch` é por vezes comparado com o `goto`. Um código usando `goto` funciona e tem um desempenho bom, mas o código rapidamente tende a virar um espaguete desorganizado e gambiarrado - o mesmo ocorre com o `switch`, só que em um grau não tão ruim assim, mas ainda ruim. O que acontece é que quase sempre há alguma outra alternativa melhor usando alguma outra coisa. No caso do `switch`, o polimorfismo é a saída mais frequente, mas há outras (tais como nas que usei acima, baseado em arrays).

Comment: @VictorStafusa + 1 pelo comentário. Foi bastante útil e esclareceu bastante. Abs.

Comment: Switch é um dos jeitos mais limpos de se fazer coisas como máquinas de estado e quaisquer outras situações de salto condicional com valores constantes, e em linguagens como C é muito mais performático do que várias outras estruturas justamente por causa das tabelas de salto. Programar bem tem muito a ver com conhecer as ferramentas especializadas e saber usar, e não só com usar ferramentas que são bonitinhas, coloridas e com cabos emborrachados. Quanto à implementação, eu não saberia dizer como é em Java a ponto de dizer se é bom ou não. Em C eu diria que é um poderoso aliado.

Comment: Em outras palavras, o `switch` em C e algumas outras linguagens não é um _syntax sugar_, e sim uma ferramenta especializada e poderosa para o que foi concebido. De forma alguma pode ser comparado com `if`, `elseif` e similares, a não ser pela "impressão" que ele passa da funcionalidade. A razão dele existir é diferente, o funcionamento interno é completamente diferente. Para entender a razão do _break_, tem que entender que só há um bloco, que é o `switch` inteiro, e não apenas `case`. Num PHP, por exemplo, isso tudo se perde. Aí sim realmente é só "mais um jeito de fazer `if`".

Comment: @Bacco O mesmo pode ser dito do `goto` - Existem situações onde ele é a melhor ferramenta. Porém, na maioria das vezes, quem o usa acaba é fazendo lambança mesmo. Concordo que máquinas de estado e saltos com base em valores numéricos, o `switch` tem o melhor desempenho, mas nem por isso ele deixa de ser algo bastante propenso a ser usado de forma incorreta, principalmente nos casos onde o polimorfismo seria a alternativa. No Java, o `switch` existe no nível do bytecode e a hotspot provavelmente vai compilar isso com JIT em algo similar ao C nos casos onde desempenho faça diferença.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, em C o `switch` é um super `goto` no sentido de funcionalidade, mas menos "perigoso" pq o destino é contido no bloco do `switch`. Acho importante que as pessoas entendam o que ele é, pois a má fama dele geralmente é culpa do mau uso (justamente originado da falta de clareza quando ensinam).

Comment: @Bacco Bem, talvez eu não tenha acertado o tom das minhas palavras no começo. A ideia não é simplesmente abolir o `switch` e não usá-lo nunca, e sim avaliar que normalmente ele não é a melhor solução. Por outro lado isso também significa que de vez em quando, em alguns casos mais específicos, ele é sim a melhor resposta. O meu alerta é mais porque tem muita gente que se apaixona quando o conhece e começa a socar `switch` a torto e a direito para fazer de tudo porque ele é bastante versátil e flexível - assim como o `goto` também é.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, posto desta forma eu tou de acordo. Pra mim o ponto importante é que (ao menos em C) as pessoas entendam que é uma ferramenta única, e com um comportamento especializado (e um blocão só, por isso o eventual uso do _break_ quando aplicável). Não uma simples alternativa a outras estruturas. E como tal, não deve ser abusada, realmente.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

O `return` acaba com a execução do método independente de onde estiver e retorna o valor.

O `break` força (manualmente) a saida de um laço ou condicional no caso o `switch`.

No segundo código se existir algo mais a ser executado depois `switch` será executado, se fosse um `return` como no primeiro exemplo o método acabaria ali mesmo.

O exemplo abaixo mostra que **nesse contexto** o uso do `break` e `return` é exatamente o mesmo, uma vez feita a escolha o método acaba nenhuma outra ação acontece.

Quanto ao uso do mais indicado para a situação alguns pontos importantes a se pensar são:

- Preciso retornar valor?
- Depois de feita a escolha (no condicional) mais alguma ação deve acontecer?
- Ao escolher o return devo utilizar a tecnica de retorno único (SESE)?

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que devo usar apenas um “return” em cada função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/91)

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/wepJxP)

---

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Com Break: "+ comBreak(1));
        System.out.println("Com Return: "+ comReturn(1));
    }

    public static String comBreak(int mes){
        String mesExtenso = "";
        switch (mes){
            case 1: 
                mesExtenso = "Janeiro";
                break;
            case 2: 
                mesExtenso = "Fevereiro";
                break;              
            case 3: 
                mesExtenso = "Março";
                break;              
            default: 
                mesExtenso = "Mês inválido";
                break;              
        }
        System.out.println("Instruções executadas antes do return");
        return mesExtenso;
    }


    public static String comReturn(int mes){

        switch (mes){
            case 1: 
                return "Janeiro";
            case 2: 
                return "Fevereiro";
            case 3: 
                return "Março";
            default: 
                return "Mês inválido";
        }
        //Qualquer instrução daqui para baixo gera o erro "unreachable statement"
        //return "Forever alone :( ....";

    }   

}
```

Comment: Só pra adicionar que o `break` é, na maioria das vezes, visto como marretada, não sendo uma boa prática de programação. Pra saber mais, sugiro o tópico http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices

Comment: @leonardopessoa tem algumas questões relacionadas (em português) [Por que o uso do “break” é considerado ruim?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131093/91) e [Deve-se usar break em for?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88747/91)

Comment: @LeonardoPessoa a questão que você linkou trata de mudanças de fluxo em situações diversas ao `switch`, em situações de repetição. O caso do `switch` é perfeitamente aplicável e fora do contexto para controle de fluxo de repetição como o da pergunta no SESE

Answer (score 10):

O `break`, só encerra a execução do `switch` e vai para a próxima instrução depois dele, é essencialmente o mesmo que ocorre em um laço. O `return` não faz algo especial dentro do `switch`, ele encerra a execução da função onde está esse código.

Foi uma infelicidade o `break` ser o mesmo comando de saída de um laço. Mais ainda ele ser obrigatório e o padrão usar em quase todas situações do `switch`.

A resposta aceita lá no SO está confusa e quase errada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Desculpe-me divergir do 'quase errada'.

A resposta no SO diz que o `RETURN` retorna imediatamente para o ponto de onde foi chamada enquanto o `break` apenas sai do loop sem retornar - ou seja a função poderia continuar fazendo outras coisas antes de retornar.

O que, no meu entender,  esta correto.

Comment: A maneira que está escrito é confusa, e dependendo de como interpretar, ela dá margem pra isso, está errada, como também dá para interpretar de outra forma e aí estaria correto, eu disse quase errada. Ela tem negativos e menos votos que outras respostas provavelmente por causa disto.

Comment: "O quase errado" é chamar um bloco switch de "loop"  - é uma construção de controle de fluxo, mas só se chama de "loop" (laço) se for uma construção que permita repetição do bloco  - como while, for etc...