# Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?

Tags: c, c++, switch

Vendo [esses comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175459/qual-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-return-e-o-break-em-um-switch-case/175460#comment364476_175459) sobre o uso do `switch` fica a dúvida como ele funciona mesmo e porque ele é diferente do `if` quando apenas comprar pela igualdade de uma variável única contra uma sequência de valores.

Como isso é compilado?

Ele deve ser preferido ao `if`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Como isso funciona é detalhe de implementação, não é especificado e você não pode se valer disto para fazer algo que só funcione se for implementado de uma forma específica.

O que nós sabemos é que o compilador faz o melhor possível para otimizar o seu uso. Nem sempre ele consegue ou é viável, por isso não há garantias do que ocorrerá. Ele pode funcionar de forma análoga ao `if` em alguns casos, mesmo que não exatamente da mesma forma.

Mas ele vai tentar gerar uma tabela de desvios ([*branch table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table)). Com isso ele precisa fazer só uma comparação e pode achar o endereço que ele deve dar um salto na execução de acordo com uma tabela, mais ou menos como um *array*.

- Obviamente precisa ser uma comparação simples com dados simples,
- deve ser denso, ou seja, não pode ter muitas lacunas entre os valores possíveis. Mesmo que não tenha algo a executar para um valor no meio da sequência, ele precisa criar um espaço na tabela para ele. Se tiver muitas lacunas o espaço ocupado pela tabela pode ser grande demais,
- precisa ter um número mínimo de opções para compensa a tabela,
- não ocorre desvios durante cada bloco de `case`.

Tem uma série de detalhes que pode variar em cada caso, mas a ideia é que uma busca que poderia levar tempo O(n), passe levar O(1). Obviamente que um bom compilador considera a arquitetura alvo e gera o código que é mais adequado para ela.

Internamente ele funciona muito como um polimorfismo.

Não ligue para os detalhes não importantes para esse assunto nos códigos abaixo.

Se criarmos um `switch` para pegar nomes de meses poderemos ver qual o Assembly gerado:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *mes(int i) {
  char *texto = (char *)malloc(10);
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        strcpy(texto, "janeiro");
        break;
      case 1:
        strcpy(texto, "fevereiro");
        break;
      case 2:
        strcpy(texto, "marco");
        break;
      case 3:
        strcpy(texto, "abril");
        break;
      case 4:
        strcpy(texto, "maio");
        break;
      case 5:
        strcpy(texto, "junho");
        break;
      case 6:
        strcpy(texto, "julho");
        break;
      case 7:
        strcpy(texto, "agosto");
        break;
      case 8:
        strcpy(texto, "setembro");
        break;
      case 9:
        strcpy(texto, "outubro");
        break;
      case 10:
        strcpy(texto, "novembro");
        break;
      case 11:
        strcpy(texto, "dezembro");
        break;
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Veja [o Assembly gerado no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/g/nbtWdf). [Também coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/Meses.c).

Aqui ele faz a comparação uma vez e acha o endereço na tabela:

```
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 11
    ja      .L2
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR .L4[0+rax*8]
    jmp     rax
```

Logo abaixo está a tabela e em seguida os blocos de código que devem ser executados.

Se fizer um `if` haverá uma comparação para cada valor:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *mes(int i) {
  char *texto = (char *)malloc(10);
    if (i == 0) {
      strcpy(texto, "janeiro");
    } else if (i == 1) {
      strcpy(texto, "fevereiro");
    } else if (i == 2) {
      strcpy(texto, "marco");
    } else if (i == 3) {
      strcpy(texto, "abril");
    } else if (i == 4) {
      strcpy(texto, "maio");
    } else if (i == 5) {
      strcpy(texto, "junho");
    } else if (i == 6) {
      strcpy(texto, "julho");
    } else if (i == 7) {
      strcpy(texto, "agosto");
    } else if (i == 8) {
      strcpy(texto, "setembro");
    } else if (i == 9) {
      strcpy(texto, "outubro");
    } else if (i == 10) {
      strcpy(texto, "novembro");
    } else if (i == 11) {
      strcpy(texto, "dezembro");
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Veja [o Assembly gerado no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/g/6iRLHM). [Também no **Github**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/MesesComIf.c).

Pode [ver o código se tiver poucas opções](https://godbolt.org/g/ogvx5f) ([**Github**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/MesesPoucasOpcoes.c)). Não otimiza tanto.

Agrupar `cases` não é um problema e otimiza, como [pode ser visto no código](https://godbolt.org/g/uYzmoX) ([**Github**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/MesesAgrupados.c)). Quando há a cascata ele coloca um item na tabela para cada `case`, mas a otimização ocorre do mesmo jeito. O `break` é usado para determinar quando deve encerrar e não continuar andando na tabela.

Já ter muitas lacunas é um problema e praticamente transforma no código do `if`. [Veja como fica](https://godbolt.org/g/5YOiDJ) ([**Github**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/MesesLacunado.c)).

Mas esse código fica melhor se for um *array* mesmo. [Veja como é mais simples](https://godbolt.org/g/KHBhde) ([**Github**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/MesesComArray.c)).

Você pode estar pensando que só pode usar um *array* se for para pegar um valor simples e guardar em algum lugar. Na verdade é possível fazer o mesmo com blocos de código em função e chamar cada função de acordo com o valor de busca, a tabela seria dos endereços das funções.

O GCC tem até uma [forma mais explícita de fazer isto](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html), mas não funciona em outros compiladores.

## Conclusão

Então é isso, a performance costuma ser melhor. Mais do que a performance deve preferir ele sempre que ele fizer sentido, sempre que for uma sequência a ser analisada. Isso valor para números, caracteres, enumerações, ou outras formas que se resumem a números simples.

O mesmo vale para muitas linguagens que prezam pela performance. Tem linguagem que tem isso mais para enfeite mesmo, ou mais para dar uma sintaxe mais adequada e não traz muita vantagem interna. Mas de forma geral ele não é só porque é mais "bonitinho", ele tem uma função própria e se for usado corretamente não tem desvantagens.

Não use onde não precisa, não tenha medo onde ele é adequado.

Comment: Pensando em alternativas de linguagens, qual forma mais fácil de saber se aquela específica está usando o jeito "mais bonitinho" e não o jeito mais performático?

Comment: @AckLay não sei se entendi o que quer saber.

Comment: Basicamente isso - com a outra diferença que nos computadores de hoje, a sequencia if/else if será quase instântanea - com várias camadas de otimização desde o código gerado pelo compilador até a previsão de saltos interna da CPU - mas quando a linguagem C foi criada podia haver  diferença de vários ciclos de clock entre a tabela de saltos gerada pelo switch/case e a sequencia de if/else if/

Comment: Mas ainda há ganho em fazer desta forma, os compiladores estão baseados em muito estudo para garantir que o que está sendo feito é o melhor sempre, tanto que se não for o melhor a otimização não é feita. Se for o mesmo resultado e ocupar mais espaço, ele já não fará a otimização. Pelo menos em compiladores decentes.