# Condição senão no javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguém saberia me explicar como coloco uma condição no script abaixo pra falar que tudo que for diferente dessas opções deve me retornar o valor 'Central'?

```
function run(cidadeFilial) {
cidadeFilial = cidadeFilial.toUpperCase();
if(cidadeFilial == 'SAO PAULO'){return 'Filial01';}
else if(cidadeFilial == 'RIO DE JANEIRO'){return 'Filial02';}
else if(cidadeFilial == 'CURITIBA'){return 'Filial03';}
else if(cidadeFilial == 'FLORIANOPOLIS'){return 'Filial03';}
else if(cidadeFilial == 'SANTOS'){return 'Filial04';}
else if(cidadeFilial == 'GUARUJA'){return 'Filial05';}
else if(cidadeFilial == 'BELO HORIZONTE'){return 'Filial05';}
```

Comment: Acredito que tenha um erro no seu código de implementação: Santos e Guarujá provavelmente deveriam ter a mesma filial, e não Guarujá e Belo Horizonte, certo? :)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu seu problema? Se a dúvida estiver solucionada, considere aceitar uma resposta. Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/100416)

Answer (score 3):

Além do `if..else` e do `switch`, que já foram apresentados, você também pode utilizar *object* e fazer a verificação das *keys*. Caso uma chave exista, retorna a filial atrelada a ela; caso contrário, retorna a filial central.

A vantagem é que você terá um código limpo e com performance semelhante à utilização do `if..else`

**Código comentado:**

```js
function cidadeFilial(cidadeFilial) {
  /* Cadastra as cidade com suas respectivas filiais */
  const filiais = {
    'SAO PAULO': 'Filial01',
    'RIO DE JANEIRO': 'Filial02',
    'CURITIBA': 'Filial03',
    'FLORIANOPOLIS': 'Filial03',
    'SANTOS': 'Filial04',
    'GUARUJA': 'Filial05',
    'BELO HORIZONTE': 'Filial05'
  }

  /**
   * Utiliza o operador "null coalescing" para verificar se
   * determinada cidade foi cadastrada no objeto
   * Se não existe (se o resultado `filiais[cidadeFilial]`)
   * for nulo, ele irá retornar a filial 'Central'; caso contrário,
   * retorna o valor da filial cadastrada.
   *
   * Código equivalente: `return (filiais[cidadeFilial]) ? filiais[cidadeFilial] : 'Central'`
   *
   * OU
   *
   * if (filiais[cidadeFilial]) return filiais[cidadeFilial]
   * else return 'Central'
   */
  return filiais[cidadeFilial] ?? 'Central'
}

console.log( cidadeFilial('GUARUJA') )
```

**Performance**

Num teste de performance, obtive os seguintes resultados:

> **If..else** x 852,585,637 ops/sec ±0.28% (67 runs sampled)
>   **Object** x 855,238,844 ops/sec ±0.25% (67 runs sampled)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode resolver isso colocando um `else` ao final do seu codigo. Isso faria o seguinte algoritmo:

```
Se a cidade for SAO PAULO
    Filial01
Se a cidade for RIO DE JANEIRO
    Filial02
...
Se não for nenhuma delas
    Central
```

```js
function run(cidadeFilial) {
  cidadeFilial = cidadeFilial.toUpperCase();
  if (cidadeFilial == 'SAO PAULO') {
    return 'Filial01';
  } else if (cidadeFilial == 'RIO DE JANEIRO') {
    return 'Filial02';
  } else if (cidadeFilial == 'CURITIBA') {
    return 'Filial03';
  } else if (cidadeFilial == 'FLORIANOPOLIS') {
    return 'Filial03';
  } else if (cidadeFilial == 'SANTOS') {
    return 'Filial04';
  } else if (cidadeFilial == 'GUARUJA') {
    return 'Filial05';
  } else if (cidadeFilial == 'BELO HORIZONTE') {
    return 'Filial05';
  } else {
    return 'Central';
  }
}

console.log(run('FLORIANOPOLIS'));
console.log(run('teste'));
```

E é possível reduzir o número de `if`s utilizando um "se A ou B". Veja exemplo abaixo:

```js
if (cidadeFilial == 'CURITIBA' || cidadeFilial == 'FLORIANOPOLIS') {
    return 'Filial03';
}
```

---

### Resolvendo com `switch`

Ao invés de usar vários `if else`, o recomendado pra esse tipo de caso é o [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), pois facilita a leitura do código e a escrita também. Se você não sabe como o `switch` funciona, dê uma lida nessa pergunta, que apesar de ser em outra linguagem, o conceito é o mesmo: [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/100416)

O algoritmo será o mesmo que o citado no começo da resposta, pois o `default` cumpre o papel de `senão` enquanto os `case`s cumprem o papel de `if (cidadeFilial == 'CIDADE')`, e você também pode agrupar as cidades que possuem a mesma filial para executar o mesmo código, veja:

```js
function run(cidadeFilial) {
  cidadeFilial = cidadeFilial.toUpperCase();
  switch (cidadeFilial) {
    case 'SAO PAULO':
      return 'Filial01';
    case 'RIO DE JANEIRO':
      return 'Filial02';
    case 'CURITIBA':
    case 'FLORIANOPOLIS':
      return 'Filial03';
    case 'SANTOS':
      return 'Filial04';
    case 'GUARUJA':
    case 'BELO HORIZONTE':
      return 'Filial05';
    default:
      return 'Central';
  }
}

console.log(run('FLORIANOPOLIS'));
console.log(run('teste'));
```

No caso das cidades com a mesma filial, aqui simplesmente é feito um "se" com duas condições:

```
Se a cidade for CURITIBA ou FLORIANOPOLIS
    Filial03
```