# Faz diferença ordenar os ifs/else ifs pelo mais provável de acontecer?

Tags: c, c++, if, desempenho

Se eu fizer

```
if (muito provável)
    //faz algo
else if (alguma probabilidade)
    //faz algo
else if (bem pouco provável)
    //faz algo
```

é melhor que colocar em qualquer outra ordem?

**Sem olhar a legibilidade**, o que o domínio pede para fazer de forma mais intuitiva, só pensando na performance, é melhor fazer assim se precisar de otimização extrema? Ou dá na mesma colocar em qualquer ordem?

Considere que reordenar não muda o resultado.

Comment: Em que contexto isto se aplicaria ?! Em uma analogia imperfeita o peso de um piloto de F1 é um fator importante o de um motorista de carreta de 100 T irrelevante, na maioria dos sistemas a clareza do código é mais importante creio.

Comment: De extrema necessidade de otimização, conforme está na pergunta.

Comment: Ok , aí sim , e é para isto que este site foi feito.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou começar dizendo que isso sempre vai depender da implementação do compilador, qual é a arquitetura alvo que vai gerar e até de certas condições.

Os processadores modernos têm um mecanismo chamado *branch prediction* onde ele tenta "adivinhar" o que vai acontecer e começa processar antecipadamente o caminho que pode acontecer. Se ele fizer certo o ganho pode ser bem grande já que hoje em dia os processadores ganham performance executando várias linhas de processamento ao mesmo tempo (não estou falando de *thread*, é só o *pipeline*). Se ele errar é um problema porque tem que fazer algo de novo que já foi gasto tempo. Ele precisa acertar mais que errar para compensar.

Então se você colocar em certa ordem e isso prejudicar o algoritmo do processador e causar *misprediction*, pode ser uma péssima ideia.

E isso pode mudar em cada geração de processador, não é só a marca dele.

E claro, pode mudar o que o compilador faz também.

E o compilador pode não ajudar tanto porque ele pode até otimizar para um tipo de processador, x86 ou ARM, por exemplo, mas não pode otimizar para um modelo específico (teoricamente poderia, mas não compensa).

Lembrando que compiladores modernos permitem você dizer quais são mais prováveis ([C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7346929/221800) e [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely), especificado na linguagem).

Para execuções pontuais pode haver ganho, para muitas repetições provavelmente o ganho será inicial, depois o processador "aprende" o que provavelmente vai acontecer e já não tem ganho mais.

De forma geral pode haver algum ganho sim em colocar o mais provável antes, mas nunca confie nisso para todos os casos.

De qualquer forma não espere ganhos muito grandes na maioria dos casos.

Note que um [`switch` pode ser diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101), ele é outra construção bem diferente, especialmente os muito longos, pode até inibir ou habilitar certas otimizações que ele pode fazer.

E até qual é a condição pode fazer uma diferença enorme. Se a condição demora muito para dar seu resultado a ordem dos `if`s fará quase nenhuma diferença em qualquer caso, a não ser que o *branch prediction* se torne impossível, aí pode fazer uma enorme diferença. E o bloco que deve executar também pode fazer o todo ser irrelevante, o grosso do tempo gasto no código não depende do *branch*.

## Conclusão

Se é tão importante tem que testar nas condições reais que serão executadas. Pode ser que consiga uma informação confiável. Aqui serve para dar uma base para pensar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer diferença, você teria de algum truque específico de compilador, indicando que o primeiro branch é o mais provável.

Por exemplo, o GCC possui a pseudo-função __builtin_expect(), que dentro do kernel do Linux é usada para compor as macros likely() e unlikely().

Alguns consideram que o branch prediction das CPUs modernas é tão bom que usar esse tipo de anotação explícita é otimização prematura e desnecessária.

Answer (score -2):

O bom de organizar dessa maneira é que exigiria menos do seu processador, já que ele não precisaria validar diversos ifs falsos até encontrar o verdadeiro e dar continuidade ao código.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).