# Como parar o "for" quando encontrar um elemento na lista?

Tags: c#, .net, loop, lista

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.Write("Nome da moto:");
string nomem = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i < ListadeVeiculos.Count; i++)
{
      if (nomem == ListadeVeiculos[i].Nomemoto)
           Console.Write("Preço R$:" +ListadeVeiculos[i].Preco.ToString("0.00"));
      else Console.Write("Moto não cadastrada!");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Tem alguma forma de parar o for quando encontrar o elemento na Lista?**

Nesse meu código se inserir 2 elementos na lista mostra a mensagem do `if` e do `else`.

Comment: Seria isso? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`break`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) encerra o laço. veja mais sobre ele em [Deve-se usar break em for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88747/101). O código ficaria melhor assim:

```
Write("Nome da moto:");
var nomeMoto = ReadLine();
var cadastrada = false;
foreach (var veiculo in ListaDeVeiculos) {
    if (nomeMoto == veiculo.NomeMoto) {
        Write($"Preço {veiculo.Preco:C");
        cadastrada = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!cadastrada) Write("Moto não cadastrada!");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/BreakLoop.cs).

A impressão que dá é que o código tem outros problemas.

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver o problema

Answer (score 2):

Existe a instrução `break` que termina um loop.

```
var motos = new List<string>
{
    "MotoA",
    "MotoB",
    "MotoC",
    "MotoD"
};

foreach (var moto in motos)
{
    if (moto.Equals("MotoC"))
    {
        break;
    }
 }
```

Mais sobre a instrução `break`

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break