# Substituir esse for por uma solução Lambda

Tags: java, expressões-lambda

Estou estudando *lambda* e queria alterar essa solução do `for` que possui um `break`.

A solução hoje me atende, porém queria saber se a maneira que estou usando é a ideal ou existe uma melhor.

Basicamente esse `for` pega os itens de 1 pedido e verifica se um dos itens pertence ao tipo TV. Se sim ele envia `true` para o front caso contrário `false`.

Gostaria de fazer essa mesma solução porém usando lambda.

O problema é que nessa solução existe um `break`, e pelo que olhei em alguns foruns não é possivel usar break no lambda.

Como poderia fazer essa solução em *lambda*.

Segue o `for` abaixo:

```
for (final AbstractEntradasPedidosModel abstractEntradasPedidosModel : pedido.getEntradas())
    {

        if (abstractEntradasPedidosModel.getProduto() instanceof TVmodel)
        {
            model.addAttribute("somenteTv", true);
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute("somenteTv", false);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Se o problema é o `break`, por que acha que uma lambda resolveria?

Comment: @AGAraujo, eu removi a tag [backend] porque ela é irrelevante para a questão. O uso de `for`/`break` versus *lambda/stream* (pelo menos da forma que está formulada a pergunta) é algo que independe do código estar ou não no backend. Inclusive, se ver a [descrição da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/back-end/info), lá diz o seguinte: *Se a dúvida não for sobre "back-end", não use esta tag, mesmo que esteja usando "back-end" no seu projeto*

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado pela informação não sabia, minha questão envolve o back, mas faz sentido o que você disse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `break`, por si só, não é um problema (veja uma discussão mais detalhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131093/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88747/112052)). Inclusive, neste caso parece ser o mais adequado, pois a intenção do código parece ser justamente essa: se encontrar um único item cujo tipo não é TV, eu posso encerrar o *loop*, pois não faz mais sentido verificar o restante dos itens, então para que continuar o `for`? Use o `break` para interrompê-lo e pronto.

O que talvez dê para melhorar é que você não precisa ficar setando o atributo para `true` toda hora (toda vez que um item é do tipo TV, você está setando novamente o mesmo atributo). Faça isso apenas uma vez, depois do `for`:

```
boolean somenteTV = true;
for (final AbstractEntradasPedidosModel abstractEntradasPedidosModel : pedido.getEntradas()) {
    if (! (abstractEntradasPedidosModel.getProduto() instanceof TVmodel)) {
        // achei um que não é TV, seta para false e sai do loop
        somenteTV = false;
        break;
    }
}
model.addAttribute("somenteTv", somenteTV);
```

Ou seja, você faz o `for` para verificar todos os itens, mas se encontrar algum que não seja TV, não precisa verificar o resto. Saia do *loop* e ao final sete o atributo com o resultado do `for`. Se todos os itens forem do tipo TV, ele não entra no `if`, e ao final do *loop* o valor do atributo será `true`.

Lembrando que neste caso, se a lista for vazia, o atrituto será `true`. Já no seu código, se a lista for vazia, ele não entra no `for`, e o atrituto sequer tem um valor setado. Se quer manter este mesmo comportamento, basta verificar se a lista `pedido.getEntradas()` (estou assumindo que é uma lista) é vazia:

```
for ...

if (pedido.getEntradas().size() > 0) {
    model.addAttribute("somenteTv", somenteTV);
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
if (pedido.getEntradas().size() > 0) {
    for...
}
```

Ou seja, se a lista for vazia, eu não seto o valor (o comportamento fica idêntico ao seu `for` original).

---

Mas se quer **mesmo** usar *lambda*, vamos lá...

Se bem que **eu acho** que você quis dizer "*streams*" (que por sua vez *podem* ser usadas com *lambdas*, e como ambos foram introduzidos no Java 8, algumas pessoas de fato confundem, ou falam um quando queriam dizer o outro, etc).

De qualquer forma, uma alternativa é:

```
boolean somenteTV = pedido.getEntradas().stream()
    .allMatch(entrada -> entrada.getProduto() instanceof TVmodel);
```

O [método `allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) verifica se todos os elementos satisfazem a condição indicada. No caso, estou verificando se todos os itens são do tipo TV. Se tiver algum que não é, o resultado é `false` (obs: o **parâmetro** passado para `allMatch` é um *lambda*).

Mas apesar de parecer que você se livrou do `for` e do `break`, é apenas uma falsa impressão. Internamente a *stream* precisa percorrer os itens da lista, e segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), nem todos os elementos serão avaliados, caso não precise ("*May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result*"). Isso dá a entender que internamente tem um `break` em algum lugar (ou no mínimo algum outro mecanismo de controle similar).

Vale lembrar também que [*streams* são bem menos eficientes que um *loop* simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052), e para casos simples como esse, nem sei se vale tanto a pena usá-las.