# Por que usar somente return, sem retornar nenhum dado?

Tags: php, sintaxe, return

Estudando o código de um *framework* me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
if (file_exists('lib/util/' . $className . '.php'))
{
     include 'lib/util/' . $className . '.php';
     return;
}
```

Qual o objetivo do uso do `return` sem ter nenhuma variável ou expressão para retornar? É possível fazer isso só no PHP ou em outras linguagens como Java também?

Comment: Parece duplicata de [Por que devo usar apenas um “return” em cada função?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/28595)

Comment: Não é duplicata, essa pergunta que você citou é sobre usar um ou vários `return` no corpo de um método. A minha é referente ao uso do `return` sem atributo para retornar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem casos em que você só quer executar uma rotina, seguir em algoritmo, um procedimento, sem gerar resultados. Ele faz uma ação, mas não produz um valor para ser usado em uma expressão. Cada linguagem pode dar um nome e um jeito de tratar isto.

Isto é possível virtualmente em todas as linguagens. Algumas exigem que esse algoritmo tenha outro nome (`procedure`, por exemplo). Falo disso em [Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101).

Matematicamente falando uma função deve retornar algum valor. Muitas linguagens permitem que elas não retornem porque não há muita vantagem prática dar outro nome só porque não retorna um valor.

Em linguagens estaticamente tipadas o normal é definir uma convenção de retorno dependendo da sintaxe dela. Algumas exigem que o tipo seja [`void`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type) (Java, por exemplo) ou algum outro nome (`unit` anda na moda). Na verdade, esse não costuma ser um tipo de dado efetivamente.

Em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica é normal a função não ter um tipo, então retornar um valor ou não, para o compilador, dá na mesma. Claro que se retornar "nada" em função que se espera o retorno de um valor, será um erro lógico (que pode ser contornado).

Já vi vários casos da função ser confusa e começa retornando um valor de um tipo, depois há uma manutenção e ela cria um outro caminho de execução e retorna sem valor. Em linguagens dinâmicas (não todas) isso costuma ser possível já que retornar nada na verdade é retornar um nulo, o que não deixa de ser um valor (diferente de um `void`).

Em tese esses procedimentos não precisam de um comando `return`. Se existir, obviamente não deve retornar valor (ou pelo menos ele será descartado em linguagens estáticas). Claro que há casos que o procedimento precisa terminar antes da sua última linha. Um comando `return` é para controle de fluxo e é usado para terminar a execução imediatamente.

Algumas linguagens, mesmo em funções completas (que retornam valor), permitem que o `return` seja omitido para produzir um resultado. Mas é claro que o comando sempre será necessário se quiser interromper a execução antes do seu fim. Este é o objetivo primário de todo `return`, retornar um valor é apenas sua função secundária. A palavra "retorno" deve ser lida como **"retorne ao local chamador"** e não "retorne um valor". Exatamente por isso tem linguagem que até usa a variável `Result` como padrão para identificar o que deve ser usado como resultado no fim da função. Embora todo mundo compreenda "retornar um valor", o correto é **"resulte um valor e retorne para o chamador"**.

Algumas linguagens permitem resultar mais de um valor (normalmente é um truque interno).

Aí do lado direito tem uma pergunta relacionada importante sobre o assunto.

[Artigo na Wikipedia sobre o `return`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement). Sobre o [tipo de retorno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_type).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

É possível. Por exemplo a função de imprimir é uma função que não retorna nada, vai apenas executar a impressão (equivalente ao include no seu exemplo) e terminar.

Comment: Seria a mesma coisa que deixar sem? Ou em outras linguagens ser um método `void`?

Comment: Não posso falar de todas as linguagens. Mas as que eu conheço, nas que é preciso declarar o tipo de variável que vai ser returnada, sim é `void`