# Para que serve o retorno de um método na linguagem C#?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, return, métodos-estáticos

Para que serve o retorno de um método na linguagem C#? Quando o método recebe os parâmetros ele gera um retorno dependendo do sua estrutura, qual seria a função deste retorno gerado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro precisa entender o que é uma função, e saber que [um método é só uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212265/101) que tem um parâmetro oculto chamado `this` que recebe o objeto que está usando, a não ser que ele seja estático. Pode ler mais sobre em [Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101) que diz que a função recebe parâmetros, executa um algoritmo e retorna um valor (se não retornar um valor é um procedimento). Também pode ver [Diferença entre um método com retorno e sem retorno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/404412/101).

Na matemática a função justamente é produzir um resultado. É ter uma fórmula que usa em vários momentos da solução de um problema geral, então em vez de ficar repetindo a mesma fórmula para todo lugar pode só chamar a função e ela produz o resultado que deseja. Além de ficar um código menor tem uma informação canônica, o que deve calcular para chegar naquele resultado, em apenas um lugar só, que provavelmente é o princípio que ajuda organizar código mais importante que a pessoa deve saber, o tal do [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Em função mesmo, que não seja só um procedimento, não faz sentido não produzir um resultado. E produzindo o resultado tem que mandar para quem chamou a função, isso é o retorno.

Por isso que se diz corretamente que a função gera um resultado, o retorno é equivocadamente usado quando isso é apenas o transporte desse valor.

O retorno, a grosso modo, é o mesmo mecanismo do parâmetro, só que inverso, o parâmetro é o meio de transporte para quem chamou enviar um valor para a função e o retorno é o mesmo para transportar de volta da função para quem chamou.

O retorno não acontece dependendo da estrutura, o valor que retorna obviamente pode variar de acordo com o algoritmo executado.

A analogia usada na outra resposta é boa, mas ela está errada. Quem chama a função está fazendo a pergunta. A pergunta pode ser até considerada o cabeçalho da função, ou seja, seu nome e parâmetros, o corpo da função é a solução do problema, ou seja, é como a resposta para a pergunta será realizada, e finalmente gerará um resultado que é a resposta da pergunta. O retorno é o que determina como a resposta será dada.

Outra coisa que pode ser de interesse da pergunta e talvez não tenha sido escrito é sobre o tipo do resultado da função, e portanto o tipo do que retorna. Em geral falamos que o tipo do resultado é o tipo da função. Estritamente não é, uma função não tem tipo, mas todo mundo entende isso como sendo o tipo do resultado.

Mais um ponto que poderia confundir é o comando `return`. Ele serve para duas coisas, determina o controle de fluxo que encerra imediatamente a execução da função e pode, na maioria das vezes, isto é, em funções de verdade, que um valor seja retornado para quem chamou. Pode ver mais em [Por que usar somente return, sem retornar nenhum dado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130990/101) e [O que o "return" faz em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115335/101).

Em C# é possível simplificar uma função de um algoritmo de uma linha e que só retorne o resultado:

```
int Soma(int x, int y) => a + b;
```

Chamando:

```
var resultado = Soma(1, 2);
```

Então `resultado` terá o valor 3.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Return.cs).

Answer (score 3):

De forma bem simples, usando uma analogia, imagine que o método é uma pergunta e o retorno do método é a resposta. A implementação do método seria a solução para chegar na resposta.

```js
function somar(a, b) {

    var resultado = a + b;

    return resultado;
}


var resultadoDaSoma = somar(1, 2);
print soma; //3
```