# Para que serve a função "return" do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return

Uma das funções que mais eu odeio é a "return" Pois  não entendo oque ela faz ou deixou de fazer vou dar um exemplo:

```
var quarter = function(number){
number / 4;
}


if (quarter(12) % 3 === 0 ) {
console.log("A declaração é verdadeira");
} else {
console.log("A declaração é falsa");
}
```

Bem, caso executem este codigo em javaScript ocorre que da "A Declaração é falsa" sendo que 12 dividido por 4 da o quociente 3, é 3 dividindo por 3, da o resto 0, que deveria dar "A declaração é verdadeira" mas por um motivo OBSCURO dá "A Declaração é falsa". Agora faremos outro teste:

```
var quarter = function(number){
 return number / 4;
}


if (quarter(12) % 3 === 0 ) {
console.log("A declaração é verdadeira");
} else {
console.log("A declaração é falsa");
}
```

Caso aos atenciosos é aqueles que não perceberão, coloquei o "return" antes da variavel "number", mas por OUTRO MOTIVO Obscuro , este exemplo, caso for executado no computador de vocês vai dar "A Declaração é verdadeira"! sendo que no primeiro exemplo só dava "A Declaração é falsa!", como apenas uma função muda algo que deveria ou não aconteçer. Quero que expliquem como funciona a variavel return oque ela faz, oque ela deixa de fazer, TODAS as suas funções é seus exemplos de funcionamento. Alem de me dizer o motivo do exemplo 1 é 2 serem diferentes. já agradeço caso leia. mas preciso muito de sua ajuda me ajudem POR FAVOR! espero falarem no chat tchau <3

Comment: [`return`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) é uma instrução.

Comment: Renan, mas eu não sei oque ela faz, caso leia atentamente o texto, minhas palavras demonstrão isto. só queria saber para que ela serve. sim eu errei , em considera-la uma "variavel" mas, quem nunca errou ou vai parar de errar na vida. ao inves de corrigir, porque não ajudar?

Comment: Minha nossa, hahaha eu só fiz um comentário. Na descrição da tag que você marcou essa pergunta há algumas informações também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/return/info

Comment: Bem, acho que as perguntas do stackoverflow não precisão das tags para serem respondidas ou perguntadas (no codigo fonte só deixa mandar perguntas com tags) mas mesmo sem tags continua a ser pergunta :)

Comment: Ta bom cara, ta bom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `return` não é uma função mas sim uma instrução (ou comando/funcionalidade) das funções em muitas linguagens de programação. O que o `return` faz é devolver um valor que é o produto da função, e com isto interrompe o resto do processamento da função.

Entre as razões de usarmos funções estão pedaços de lógica complexos ou necessidade de reutilizar o mesmo código com dados de entrada diferentes. Ora a maneira de a função retornarem o que nós queremos desses pedaços de código (funções) é usando `return`.

Quando uma função acaba sem ter chamado um `return` o valor que ela deixa ou retorna é `undefined`.

Dá uma olhada a estes exemplos:

```
function foo(){
   // sem nada
}

function bar(){
    return 10;
}

console.log(foo()); // dá undefined
console.log(bar()); // dá 10
```

A diferênça, como no teu exemplo, é que o return devolve o resultado da função. E esse resultado pode ser guardado numa variável! Olha este exemplo:

```
var a = bar();
console.log(a); // 10
```

dá `10` porque o valor de retorno da função foi agora guardado na variável.

No teu primeiro exemplo quando tens no final da função somente `number / 4;`, sem o `return`, o interpretador corre esse comando, ou seka calcula a quarta parte de `number` mas não passa esse valor de volta a quem chamou a função. Para isso precisas de `return number / 4;`

Comment: Bem, sergio como pecebi em seu codigo você ultilizou no segundo exemplo "return 10;" sendo que no 1 não havia nada, oque faria de diferente? caso so colocaçe o 10 sem o "return"?

Comment: @BrunoTerroLiveHabbo só com `10` sem `return` daria `undefined`. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/dd14h5z5/

Comment: Sergio. quando você mandou o link analisei é percebi algo: que sem o return fica undefined mais com o return ele RETORNA 10 para a função FOO ou não?

Comment: @BrunoTerroLiveHabbo exato. O return "é a voz da função" que diz o que se passa lá dentro. Sem `return` nada sai da função, ela faz o que deve fazer mas não dá retorno.

Comment: Então... devo usar return no final de todas as minhas funções? é caso eu ultilize o "var" dentro da função é ele precisse do "return" não vai modificar o retorno?

Comment: @BrunoTerroLiveHabbo usa o `return` quando precisares do resultado da função. Nem todas as funções precisam de return, algumas chamam outras funções como maneira de dar continuidade ao programa, outras mudam coisas na página ou gravam na base de dados. Depende do caso.

Comment: No caso, algumas precisão do return é outras não certo? então porque colocamos apenas o return no final?

Comment: @BrunoTerroLiveHabbo o return não tem de estar no final. Coloca onde der mais jeito. Normalmente o código é sequencial e por isso o `return` vem no final, mas coloca onde fôr necessário. E dá uma leitura aqui também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2477/por-que-devo-usar-apenas-um-return-em-cada-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o?rq=1

Comment: Cara você me ajudou muito parabens, nem profissionais consiguirão me explicar de uma forma que eu consiga entender direito, mais você explicou é eu entendi muito obrigado por ter perdido uns minutos da sua vida com um ser que não entendia uma coisa tão simples <3

Comment: Mas só a ultima pergunta: é caso a minha função tiver 2 parametros ( Ou ate mais )? exemplo: var len = function per(V,B){
      return V + B;
}
No caso, o return vai dar o resultado da função no V ou no B? O.O

Comment: @BrunoTerroLiveHabbo quando usas `return V + B;` é o mesmo que `return (V + B);` ou seja o `return` exporta o resultado de `V + B`.