# Usar "if/elif/else" com o return é boa prática de programação?

Tags: python

Ex.:

```
return (sum*2 if a == b else sum)
```

Comment: Se a pergunta é de if, elif e else é duplicata de [Por que devo usar apenas um "return" em cada função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2477/70) - que é diferente do seu exemplo.

Comment: Agora, se quer saber do if inline apenas, seria bom deixar especifico (ai nao é duplicata, é um problema à parte mesmo, mas ainda assim é estranho, pois qual problema teria, ou qual seria a diferença para a multiplicação usada?)

Comment: Você tem algum motivo específico para fazer esta pergunta? Viu em algum lugar? Consegue ver algum problema?

Comment: Só pra esclarecer melhor: o `if` de bloco é controle de fluxo, o inline ja é um operador.

Comment: Eu só queria saber se  usar o return com if e else, no lugar de blocos de código (como foi respondido abaixo) diminui a qualidade do código, se atrapalha na legibilidade.

Answer (score 3):

O único problema que vejo seria a legibilidade , que no caso até dá pra entender tranquilo , mas se houver mais níveis aí começa a complicar.

Mas se estiver no sentido de blocos não vejo muito problemas, o que eu alteraria seria só um detalhe, no caso de houver if , elif e else para ocorrer o processamento , definiria um valor inicial para a variável e dependendo do fluxo que tome irá sobrescrevendo o valor , com isso só retorno ele no final, com o valor já definido.

**Ex:**

```
def get_desconto(compra):

    if compra.valor_total <= 500:
        desconto = 0.05
    elif ( compra.valor_total >= 600 ) and ( compra.valor_total <= 1000 ):
        desconto = 0.1
    else:
        desconto = 0.3

    return desconto * compra.valor_total
```

Com isso dependendo do fluxo que pode ocorrer o valor de desconto muda.. E somente o final faço o cálculo final.