# O que é uma guard clause?

Tags: funções, design-pattern, condição

O que é uma *guard clause*?

Possíveis traduções e sinônimos:

- Cláusula de guarda
- Condição de guarda
- Cláusula-sentinela
- Cláusula de prevenção
- Cláusula de proteção

[Definição mais completa](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

Quais suas vantagens? O código fica mais legível com elas (via de regra)?

Comment: Veja os guards de função, que é algo built-in no Elixir: https://elixirschool.com/pt/lessons/basics/functions/#guards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No contexto da pergunta são aquelas condições que preparam o terreno para a real execução do código filtrando o que fará e principalmente se pode fazer.

São condições que o algoritmo precisa assegurar antes de executar a ação que ele está preparado para fazer.

Algumas pessoas conhecem esse padrão como **pré-condição** e de fato é muito usado como contratos de uma função.

Pode ser desde uma validação básica de um argumento recebido para avaliar se é do tipo esperado, se não é nulo, se está dentro de uma determinada faixa, ou se algum dado está em determinado estado, mesmo que não seja sobre os argumentos da função (ainda que isto seria feito no objeto que foi recebido implicitamente por um método). E pode ser uma validação de regra de negócio como determinar se tem saldo suficiente para realizar aquilo (um saque por exemplo).

Exemplos:

```
draw() {
    if (!isVisible()) return; //se não estiver visível não tem porque desenhar
    ...
}

bool saque(int valor) {
    if (saldo - valor + limite < 0) return false;
    ...
}

T getElement(int index) {
    if (index >= this.length) throw new OutOfBounds();
    ...
}

T join(T a, T b) {
    if (a == null) return b; //não precisa fazer a operação se o outro não existe
    if (b == null) return a;
    ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Guard.java).

Não precisa ser apenas uma condição, e pode constar todas que forem necessárias.

Algumas linguagens possuem mecanismos que facilitam isso, que permitem evitar certas verificações, pelo menos do mecanismo delas. Algumas tem até um `if` de uma forma especial que facilita isso, ou que dá mais semântica a esta parte. Mas é aquilo que eu sempre falo, é um *design pattern* tão importante que colocaram na sintaxe.

Geralmente ela se opõe a colocar vários `if`s aninhados ou tomar decisões posteriores no meio da execução. Com esse padrão você tende a deixar mais legível aumentando a produtividade do programador por ver logo de início se está tudo ok. Fica muito mais fácil analisar as condições necessárias para uso daquilo, que é o que importa muitas vezes.

E há ganho na execução a performance tenderá ser melhor porque não perder tempo com algo que não tem futuro.

Tem a ver com isso também: [Por que devo usar apenas um "return" em cada função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/101).

Answer (score 5):

Cláusula de guarda é uma cláusula quer permite validar uma variável, normalmente um input, e garantir que ela tem um valor que seja possível utilizar no código.

Não é uma validação de negócio, como por exemplo se uma data é posterior a data atual, é por exemplo:

- Se um valor não é nulo;
- Se um valor de um número identificador não é zero;
- Se uma string não está nula ou vazia;
- Se uma injeção de dependência foi corretamente injetada

Alguns exemplos apenas, mas o objetivo é fazer a salvaguarda do método/função/módulo de que os valores tem o mínimo para poder seguir com a execução do código.

Veja por exemplo esse código:

```
public void Calcular(AlgumaClasse obj, int valor)
{
   var x = obl.Total / valor;
}
```

O que vai acontecer se o `obj` estiver nulo, ou `valor` for igual a zero? Vai dar de referência nula e/ou divisão por zero.

Um *guard clause* aqui podeira ser assim:

```
public void Calcular(AlgumaClasse obj, int valor)
{
   if (obj == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("obj não pode ser nulo");
   }

   if (valor == 0)
   {
       throw new ArgumentInvalidException("valor não pode ser zero");
   }

   var x = obj.Total / valor;
}
```

Portanto o código teria uma salvaguarda com valores mal informados, lembrando que é só um exemplo da estrutura de como guardar o código, que pode ser implementado de diversas maneiras.

Podem ser usadas expressões para fazer a validação. Em `C#` podemos ter:

```
var total = obj == null ? 0 : obj.Total;
var total = obj?.Total;  // só exemplo, total sera null, vai falhar em seguida
var div = valor == 0 ? 1 : valor;
```

Answer (score 3):

A grosso modo

`Guards` é um mecanismo que permite o compilador inferir o estado de uma variável.

Sua implementação depende da linguagem, mas um tipo de guarda bastante utilizado é para proteger o código de acessar uma referencia nula. Você tem esse mecanismo em linguagens como Kotlin, TypeScript e C# (acima da versão 8).

Como funciona:

```kotlin
// uma variável null-able do tipo inteiro é declarada
val i: Int? = null

// uma variável não null-able do tipo inteiro é declarada
val j: Int = 10

// com o mecanismo de guards ativado, isso resulta num erro de compilação
// pois i não é garantido de ser um inteiro válido
val soma1 = i + j

// utilizando uma condição de guarda, o código se torna válido, pois aqui é
// possível inferir que j será somado com um valor válido
val soma2 = (i ?: 0) + j

// aqui temos uma capsula de guarda, o compilador consegue inferir
// que dentro desse escopo, i não é null
if (i != null) {
    // utilizar i como um inteiro dentro desse escopo é válido
    var soma3 = i + j
}
```

Esse mecanismo também pode ser utilizado para inferir o tipo da variável, como por exemplo, em TypeScript, onde variáveis podem ser declaradas como tipo algébrico:

```js
function test(valor: number | number[]) {
    // dentro desse contexto, valor pode ser tanto um número, quanto um array de números
    // portanto é necessário utilizar algum tipo de guarda para tratarmos a variável

    if (Array.isArray(valor)) {
        // Array.isArray define uma guarda, dentro desse escopo o compilador nos
        // permite tratar valor como um array

    } else {
        // A guarda também permite inferir que dentro desse escopo, valor não é
        // um array, e logo é possível trata-lo como um número nesse escopo
    }
}
```