# Como eu faço o programa identificar se denominador da divisão é zero usando switch-case e exibir uma mensagem de invalidez na operação?

Tags: c

Tenho este exercício pra fazer e tudo está correndo bem, porém eu não sei como fazer o programa analisar se o denominador é zero e exibir a mensagem, podem me ajudar?

[image: Enunciado do exercício]

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a, b;
char o;

printf("Digite dois valores inteiros:\n");
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

printf("\nDigite um caracter de soma, subtracao, divisao ou multiplicacao:\n");
scanf(" %c", &o);

switch (o){
    case '+': printf("\nO resultado da soma eh: %d\n", a + b);
              break;
    case '-': printf("\nO resultado da subtracao eh: %d\n", a - b);
              break;
    case '*': printf("\nO resultado da multiplicacao eh: %d\n", a * b);
              break;
    case '/': printf("\nO resultado da divisao eh: %d\n", a / b);
              break;
    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar um `if`? Algo como `if (b ==0) { printf("Denominador zero é proibido.\n"); }`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eu posso utilizar `if` dentro de `switch-case`?

Pode. O `case` de um `switch` *statement* em C não é exclusivo para expressões. Você pode colocar *statements* (declarações) dentro deles também. Isso inclui, por exemplo, um `if`. O próprio `break` é um *statement*.

Portanto, bastaria verificar se o denominador é zero utilizando o `if` dentro do caso da divisão. Assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    char o;

    printf("Digite dois valores inteiros:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

    printf("\nDigite um caracter de soma, subtracao, divisao ou multiplicacao:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &o);

    switch (o){
        case '+':
            printf("\nO resultado da soma eh: %d\n", a + b);
            break;

        case '-':
            printf("\nO resultado da subtracao eh: %d\n", a - b);
            break;

      case '*':
          printf("\nO resultado da multiplicacao eh: %d\n", a * b);
          break;

      case '/':
        if (b == 0) {
            printf("\nDenominador zero é inválido.\n");
            return 1; // Retornar 1 (código de saída padrão para erros.)
        }

        printf("\nO resultado da divisao eh: %d\n", a / b);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-483791#main.c).</sup>

Note, no código acima, que não utilizei um `else` após o `if`. Fiz isso porque o `return` elimina a necessidade do `else`, já que encerra a função, retornando desta o valor passado. Saiba mais sobre esse padrão [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/69296).

Comment: Muito obrigado! s2