# Muitos "returns" em uma função é ruim?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, visual-studio-code, estilo-de-codificação, revisão-de-código

Após instalar o SonarLint no VSCode, a extensão acusou minha função de ter "muitos retornos":

> This function has 8 returns, which is more than the 3 allowed. [+8 locations] sonarlint(php:S1142)
>
> <sub>"Essa função têm 8 retornos, o que é maior que 3 permitidos. [+8 locais]"</sub>

A função no caso é esta:

```php
function human_consulta_status(int $consulta_status): string
{
    switch ($consulta_status) {
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_CREATED:
            return "Em análise";
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_PERFORMED:
            return "Concluído";
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_SCHEDULED:
            return "Agendado";
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_RESCHEDULED:
            return "Remarcado";
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_PAYMENT_DECLINED:
            return "Pagamento rejeitado";
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_PAYMENT_APPROVED:
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_WAITING_SCHEDULE:
            return "Aguardando agendamento";
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_CANCELLED_BY_MEDICO:
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_CANCELLED_BY_SECRETARIO:
        case CONSULTA_STATUS_CANCELLED_BY_CLIENT:
            return "Cancelado";
        default:
            return "Desconhecido";
    }
}
```

Claramente é visível que existem bastantes retornos na função, mas não entendi o ponto da extensão dizer que isso "é ruim". O que está errado em usar "vários retornos" em uma função?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você quer seguir regras que algum "gênio" da programação criou? É isto que está fazendo.

Em geral essas ferramentas de ajuda com codificação são assim, elas ajudam em alguns pontos e atrapalham em outros. Eles precisam colocar um monte de coisa para parecer que são bons, que tem muito "feature". Estilo de codificação não é universal.

Esta sugestão está dizendo para fazer algo ruim para atender uma regra sem sentido. A solução que você teria é criar uma variável sem sentido algum, guardar o valor nela e colocar só um `return` com ela, só para atender a regra.

No mínimo deveria desligar essa regra, quem sabe desligar toda ferramenta para não ensinar outras coisas sem sentido. Um programador mais incauto e que não queira perguntar começará seguir isto e piorará seu código.

Mas se quiser muito tirar isso, sem criar essa variável, pode criar um *array* com todas as *strings* (terá que repetir algumas, conforme mostra o código) e de acordo com o valor da variável de status pegar pelo índice/chave do *array* qual é a *string* que será usada.

Sem contexto, regras de codificação não fazem sentido nunca, mesmo que acerte por coincidência. É a tal da "boa prática", alguém dizendo o que você deve fazer sem saber o que está acontecendo de verdade em situação real.

[Para saber mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/101).

Comment: Existe MUITO disso por aí. Várias extensões que prometem "limpar o seu código", inclusive cursos também. Essas ferramentas não conseguem deduzir de fato o que seu código tá fazendo, por isso acaba implicando essas regras bobas.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se fica ruim, mas... Estou evitando de usar `switch`.

Você pode usar `match` a parti do `PHP8`

```
function human_consulta_status(int $consulta_status): string
{
    return match ($consulta_status) {
        CONSULTA_STATUS_CREATED => "Em análise",
        CONSULTA_STATUS_PERFORMED => "Concluído",
        CONSULTA_STATUS_SCHEDULED => "Agendado",
        CONSULTA_STATUS_RESCHEDULED => "Remarcado",
        CONSULTA_STATUS_PAYMENT_DECLINED => "Pagamento rejeitado",
        CONSULTA_STATUS_PAYMENT_APPROVED,
        CONSULTA_STATUS_WAITING_SCHEDULE => "Aguardando agendamento",
        CONSULTA_STATUS_CANCELLED_BY_MEDICO,
        CONSULTA_STATUS_CANCELLED_BY_SECRETARIO,
        CONSULTA_STATUS_CANCELLED_BY_CLIENT => "Cancelado",
        default => "Desconhecido",
    };
}
```

Ai você evita usar muitos `return`, fica uma abordagem mais limpa.

referência https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.match.php

Comment: Essa pergunta não foi bem sobre o trecho de código. Usei apenas um exemplo nele. De qualquer jeito, não sabia dessa estrutura, então vou dar upvote porque achei interessante.